# Is there a way to get a derived class' type in a base class' function?

Tags: c++, function, types, abstract-class

I'm looking for a way to use the type of a derived class in a function in the base class, similar to templatized functions.

```
class Base
{
    T foo() const
    {
        return T(*this);
    }
}

class Derived : public Base
{
}
```

This is similar to what I want to use this for, so that I don't have to override foo as a pure virtual function in every derived class. The goal is to find a way for T in foo to be the type of the derived class. For example, calling foo on an object of type Derived should call a version of foo that looks like
this:

```
Derived foo() const
{
    return Derived(*this);
}
```

I know this probably isn't something you can do, but can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can make `Base` a template, and instantiate it with `Derived` when inheriting from it. This is referred to as the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP):

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
  public:
    T foo() const
    {
        return T(*this);
    }
};

class Derived : public Base<Derived>
{
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7eqGjE).

Comment: Thank you! That'll save quite a bit of needless redefining